# Using radio button to change parameter in a function

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-maps-api-3, radio-button

I have been working through the [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) tutorial.
The author of that tutorial uses a drop-down `<select>` list of radius values to search by.
Instead of this list, I would like to have a series of radio buttons, with search radius options associated to them.

I have the buttons, but they are not behaving in the manner in which I expected - the radius value of the button doesn't seem to be being added to the function `searchLocationsNear`, when I click on it. (The radius value of the first button is being passed to the function ok.)

I assumed that as the first part of the function was `clearLocations()`, that would mean that whatever value `radiusSelect` was would be removed and replaced with the new number from the radio button.

Could someone please tell me where I need to be looking to make this work?

Thanks

Javascript of the function:

```
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations();

     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'xml_output.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address2");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }
```

The html of the search area:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radiusSelect" value="1">1 miles</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radiusSelect" value="10">10 miles</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radiusSelect" value="30">30 miles</label>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Not that HTML requires each element have a **unique** id (you have multiple elements with id="radiusSelect"). Have you researched how to get the value of an array of radio buttons?

Comment: How would you like me to provide a better example? Should I edit my original question with the entire code?
I was assuming that because I named each of the options id="radiusSelect" that would mean they would replace one another in the function, when their corresponding radio button was selected...
Can you suggest something I should read about arrays of buttons?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ID's must be unique, but you use the same ID `radiusSelect` multiple times
2. you must iterate over all buttons, check if the `checked`-property of the current button is true, when it does set  `radius` to the `value` of the button:

---

```
 var radius = ( function(n,r){
                  var b=document.getElementsByName(n);
                  for(var i=0;i<b.length;++i){
                    if(b[i].checked)return b[i].value;
                  }
                  return r;
                }
                ( 'radio',//name of the buttons
                  1//default-radius
                ));
```

Comment: Thanks, I see now. I need to make it check which radio button is selected, then use that value.
Can you suggest something I should read to further my understanding of this?

Comment: It's very basic JS/DOM, what exactly do you want to understand?

Comment: I'm afraid you're talking to a very inexperienced coder (what's DOM?) - could you recommend a good Javascript tutorial?

Comment: It's a little bit to broad for a tutorial... you may see the DOM as a JS-driver for documents(HTML, XML and more)...it implements interfaces which allow you to interact with documents. A good start might be http://help.dottoro.com/ljhrmrfb.php